# How to merge cURL responses into one json?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I want the result of my file display to be modified.

It shows the JSON file side by side but I want it to be combined

My code is:

```
<?php

$curlData = array(
  array(
    'url' => 'https://example.com/list',
    'cookie' => 'session=example'
  ),
  array(
    'url' => 'https://anotherdomain.com/list',
    'cookie' => 'session=another'
  ),
  // Add more domains and cookies as needed
);

$responses = array();

foreach ($curlData as $data) {
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $data['url'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'Cookie: ' . $data['cookie']
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  $responses[] = $response;
}

// Output the responses
foreach ($responses as $response) {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

My result response JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "",
    "obj": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "remark": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 159,
            "remark": "mssdss"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "",
    "obj": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "remark": "tttt"
        },
        {
            "id": 56,
            "remark": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want merge result:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "",
    "obj": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "remark": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 159,
            "remark": "mssdss"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "remark": "tttt"
        },
        {
            "id": 56,
            "remark": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "remark": "D"
    },
    {
        "id": 159,
        "remark": "mssdss"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "remark": "tttt"
    },
    {
        "id": 56,
        "remark": "ok"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have access to the other domain's code that presents this response? If not, you'll probably need to get creative with some string parsing and/or regex.

Comment: I can't change the codes of the sites. Just change my code and guide me please.

Comment: If your system has the `jq` utility installed, add a tag to your Q for `jq` and possibly a `jq` guru will help you out. Good luck.

Comment: I missed the fact that you were doing these in a loop. My mistake.

Comment: I will say that your first example of what you wanted isn't really a good idea, because you're assuming that the metadata for each will be the same. It's a better idea to handle that in your loop and skip the processing if it's not in a `success: true` state. Then just keep the data from the `->obj` array, and merge that as I suggested below.

Comment: Why not merge them how you would merge all other JSON files? Is this really related to cURL?

Answer (score 2):

The sample data that you provided makes a simple merge of the `obj` key suffice. ([3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PdcK8))

```php
$mergedResponse = json_encode(
    array_merge(
        json_decode($responseOne, true)['obj'],
        json_decode($responseTwo, true)['obj']
    )
);
```

This would be the merged response:

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "remark":"D"
   },
   {
      "id":159,
      "remark":"mssdss"
   },
   {
      "id":14,
      "remark":"tttt"
   },
   {
      "id":56,
      "remark":"ok"
   }
]
```

Please note that any duplicate keys in the second response would override them in the first response.

Comment: I don't want duplicate data to be deleted.. Where did you correct my code? Please completely change the first code.

Comment: @world The question doesn't mention duplicate data, or how you want to manage it. Please **Edit** the question and explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
php > $r1 = <<<EOT
<<< > {
    "success": true,
    "msg": "",
    "obj": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "remark": "D"
        },
        {
            "id": 159,
            "remark": "mssdss"
        }
    ]
}
<<< > EOT;
php > $r2 = <<<EOT
<<< > {
    "success": true,
    "msg": "",
    "obj": [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "remark": "tttt"
        },
        {
            "id": 56,
            "remark": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
<<< > EOT;
php > $response1 = json_decode($r1);
php > $response2 = json_decode($r2);
php > $merged = array_merge($response1->obj, $response2->obj);
php > print_r($merged);
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [remark] => D
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 159
            [remark] => mssdss
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [remark] => tttt
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 56
            [remark] => ok
        )

)
php >
```

Edit: You could also do this in a longhanded fashion:

```
// Assume everything is set up as in the above example

$result = [];

foreach ($response1->obj as $obj)
{
    $result[] = $obj;
}

foreach ($response2->obj as $obj)
{
    $result[] = $obj;
}

// $result is now an array of all the objects from your requests, allowing for duplicate objects
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing as what @D1_1 shared, now that I look it over.

Comment: Also, if you need it in JSON again, just `json_encode()` the `$result` array.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably more accurate to say that you want to "append" data instead of merging.  I recommend that if you encounter an unsuccessful payload, then you should throw an exception and handle the issue.  Otherwise, if the result variable hasn't been populated, then fill it with the first full payload.  Any subsequently encountered successful payload should only have its `obj` data pushed into the result variable's `obj` property.  If you want to return the resultant data as a json string, just call `json_encode()` on it at the end.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/34mRd))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($curlData as $data) {
    // ...your curl code
    $obj = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    if (!$obj->success) {
        throw new Exception($obj->msg);
    }
    if (!$result) {
        $result = $obj;  // store full payload
    } else {
        array_push($result->obj, ...$obj->obj); // append only obj data
    }
}
var_export($result);
```